# SQL Finding most recent record by group

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, greatest-n-per-group

I have an approval history table for my workflow app that contains the following structure with some junk data:

```
Table: [Approval]
+--------------------------------------+-------+----------------+-------------------------+
| ID                                   |Status | UserID         | DateStamp               |
+--------------------------------------+-------+----------------+-------------------------+
| 63DDD358-EF3B-4355-8251-00CDE8560B3E | 5     |User1           | 2014-12-09 11:53:40.423 |
| 63DDD358-EF3B-4355-8251-00CDE8560B3E | 10    |User1           | 2014-12-09 11:53:40.423 |
| 13F65DDC-73D8-48BB-87F4-0207DE47A6D9 | 5     |User2           | 2016-02-19 11:10:56.820 |
| 13F65DDC-73D8-48BB-87F4-0207DE47A6D9 | 10    |User3           | 2016-02-19 11:10:56.820 |
| 5AB3C39E-8E2E-4935-BC6C-0226F444D7F2 | 5     |User1           | 2014-09-18 14:53:07.973 |
| 5AB3C39E-8E2E-4935-BC6C-0226F444D7F2 | 20    |User3           | 2014-09-18 14:56:07.177 |
| 5AB3C39E-8E2E-4935-BC6C-0226F444D7F2 | 60    |User1           | 2014-09-18 14:53:07.973 |
| 5AB3C39E-8E2E-4935-BC6C-0226F444D7F2 | 70    |User1           | 2014-09-18 14:56:08.177 |
| 5AB3C39E-8E2E-4935-BC6C-0226F444D7F2 | 70    |User1           | 2014-10-15 15:17:49.210 |
| 5AB3C39E-8E2E-4935-BC6C-0226F444D7F2 | 90    | System         | 2014-10-15 15:17:50.210 |
+--------------------------------------+-------+----------------+-------------------------+
```

The Status codes all indicate levels of Approval and 90 is complete, cancelled is 99.

I need to find the requests that are awaiting approval that have not yet been completed or cancelled by finding the top row when grouping the data. This will then be used to send an email reminding the user that have an approval outstanding

So far I have this query:

```
SELECT a.ID,a.Status,a.ApproverID,A.DateTime FROM Approval a
INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT MAX(DateTime) as MaxDate, Status FROM Approval
    WHERE Status not in (90,99)
    GROUP BY Status
    ) a1 ON a1.MaxDate = a.DateTime and a1.Status = a.Status
```

This groups the data and gives me the most recent record, but it doesn't ignore anything that has already been completed or cancelled.

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What would be the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT a.ID,a.Status,a.ApproverID,A.DateTime, 
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY A.DateTime DESC)
FROM   Approval a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (
           SELECT *
           FROM   Approval x
           WHERE  x.ID = a.ID
           AND    x.Status in (90, 99)
       )
) A
WHERE A.RN = 1
```

RN = 1 will give you the latest record by ID

NOT EXISTS() is to exclude an ID that is having 90 or 99 status

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`FIRST_VALUE`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx):

```
SELECT ID, Status, UserID, DateStamp
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Status, UserID, DateStamp,
         FIRST_VALUE(Status) OVER (PARTITION BY ID 
                                   ORDER BY DateStamp DESC) AS last_status
  FROM Approval) AS t
WHERE  last_status NOT IN (90,99)
```

`FIRST_VALUE` returns the *top* row per `ID` partition: if the value of this row is either `90`, or `99` then the whole partition is filtered out.

If you want to filter out `ID` partitions having a value of either `90`, or `99` *anywhere* in time, then use the following query:

```
SELECT ID, Status, UserID, DateStamp
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Status, UserID, DateStamp,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN Status IN (90,99) THEN 1 END) OVER 
         (PARTITION BY ID) AS cnt_status
  FROM Approval) AS t
WHERE  cnt_status = 0
```

Comment: Hi Giorgos, Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know about the FIRST_VALUE function. In this case I'm using SQL Server 2008, but will keep that in mind for future reference